# getting json from string

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following json object

```
"phrase": "{subject: Hello}"
```

When I access "phrase" it returns `"{subject: Hello}"` as a string but I want this string to be converted to json object.

Comment: {subject: Hello} isn't a valid JSON, so either make it valid (adding " around keys and values), or parse it yourself

Comment: How did you create `"phrase": "{subject: Hello}"`? You should fix your code at that end and create valid JSON or a valid JavaScript object. Also be careful with the terminology. JSON is a data exchange format, not a data type. I assume you want to create a **JavaScript** object out of `"{subject: Hello}"`. If you really want some help, you have to provide more information.

Comment: I am getting a large json object from from a java program. this large json in turn contains a a key (i.e. "phrase") value ("{subject: Hello}") pair whose value (means "{subject: Hello}") itself is supposed to be a json object.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called `JSON.parse` to convert things from strings to objects but I am not sure it would apply to your case, since you have invalid JSON (the "Hello" not being quoted is a bid deal and the "subject" not being quoted is a bad sign)

Comment: `{subject: Hello}` is not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Javascript object literal, just remove the quotation marks when you create it:

```
var phrase = { subject: "Hello" };
```

If it's a JSON string that is parsed, change the string to an object:

```
{ "phrase": { "subject": "Hello" } }
```

If you have a variable that contains a JSON string, you need to make it valid JSON to parse it:

```
var phrase = '{ "subject": "Hello" }';
var obj = JSON.parse(phrase);
```

You can also parse the string as Javascript, which has a more relaxed syntax. The string value needs delimiters though:

```
var phrase = '{ subject: "Hello" }';
var obj = eval(phrase);
```

Note that the `eval` function actually *executes* the string as javascript, so you need to know where the string value comes from for this to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

you could use native JSON parsing with `JSON.parse(jsonString);` 
(Edit: assuming to have a valid JSON object)

Comment: `{subject: Hello}` is not JSON.

Comment: sorry I didn't notice the missing quotes

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse()`:

```
var obj = {myObj:"{\"this\":\"that\"}"};
obj.myObj = JSON.parse(obj.myObj);
alert(obj.myObj["this"]);
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B97ef/).